# t-test random sample assumption violated?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have a problem similar to the following:

Suppose that for six days I ask my friend bob to make a prediction on the average temperature of the following day. Then I ask my friend Alice for the following six days the same. So I end up with a dataset like this:

| Day | friend | prediction | error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| day 1 | bob | b1 | e1 |
| day 2 | bob | b2 | e2 |
| day 3 | bob | b3 | e3 |
| day 4 | bob | b4 | e4 |
| day 5 | bob | b5 | e5 |
| day 6 | bob | b6 | e6 |
| day 7 | alice | a1 | e7 |
| day 8 | alice | a2 | e8 |
| day 9 | alice | a3 | e9 |
| day 10 | alice | a4 | e10 |
| day 11 | alice | a5 | e11 |
| day 12 | alice | a6 | e12 |

Where the errors $e1,e2,...,e12$ represent the absolute difference between the prediction and the actual average temperature of the day. My goal is to test if the predictions of bob are more accurate than the predictions of Alice. I was planning on doing a t-test on the means of the errors.

One of the assumptions of a t-test is that data of each group comes from a random sample, in my problem, is this assumption violated? If it is not, What is the reference population of each group? Because of this, I was thinking  on performing a Bayesian test instead of the t-test, is this the correct approach? How should I attack this problem?

Comment: Why not get your friends to independently predict temperatures for the same days? That would eliminate the problem that average temperatures for some days will be more difficult to predict than other days.

Comment: Have you thought about the possibility that one person might be fairly precise in estimating the temperature but inaccurate, whereas another might be imprecise but more accurate? Sometimes you should be interested in more than just the mean.

Comment: Consider having the people predict on the same days and using a permuations test to test the hypothesis that Bob and Alice are equivalent in their abilities to predict temperatures. You will have fewer unrealistic assumptions than with a t-test.

Comment: Replacing T-test with Bayesian will not fix the problem. The problem is that you have confounded 2 separate issues (person and day) in your sampling, Any method you throw at it will have to guess how much of the observed effect is due to person and how much is due to day. You can of course make some assumptions - but any conclusions will be tempered by the underlying assumptions which will need validated to progress insight any further.

Comment: Using paired measurements will be a great improvement. But still, the assumptions remain invalid and you may have large errors in computing the t-value.

Comment: @MichaelLew This is a self imposed problem I am using to learn more about t-test, I could have data for the same days, but I'm interested in the current case, were data is collected at different days.

Comment: @MichaelLew The comment about precision and accuracy is very interesting. Do you have a reference or the name of the topic so that I can read more about?

Comment: @ReneBt True, my assumption is that predicting the average temperature difficulty is independent of the day.  This might be reasonable if there are no external or extreme weather conditions happening in the measured days (i believe). Supposing my assumption is true, is the random sample violated? Thats the thing I have the most interest

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Sorry, does paired measurements means having Alice and Bob make prediction on the same days?

Comment: A badly designed experiment cannot be rescued by statistical analysis. If you want to compare the prediction abilities of Bob and Alice you need to collect data that allow a good comparison. If you are interested in what you can learn from your example, the lesson is about the confounding stated by @ReneBT and implied by my comments.

Comment: Your comment 'my assumption is that predicting the average temperature difficulty is independent of the day' is correct, but your conclusions must be tempered with 'assuming the error in temperature prediction is independent of the day'. Based on human psychology and physiology this is a very dangerous assumption. It highly reasonable that some people will be cold biased, some warm biased. If Bob feels cold more accurately, but Alice feels warmth more accurately then differences in temperature on the block of days may be what you end up measuring, not differences in the person's accuracy.

Comment: Temperature bias will not be stable but also be affected by illness, stress etc that could coincide with the day sampling.   So you limit the scope of your conclusions if you don't control other factors.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that the errors will have some correlation. You need to figure out this correlation structure and use that estimate to estimate the standard error of the mean error/difference between the prediction and observation.

In addition, a problem is that this correlation is not constant. You can have different situations that cause errors. For instance, if a certain weather depression passes by then the problem is *where* and *when* the temperature will drop, and not so much *how* much it will drop. If an error is made in time then the error can be large for one day but good the next day.

So yes the t-test assumption can be strongly violated.

If the errors are positively correlated then you will observe a smaller in-between variation of the error (it is like there is a fluctuation in the systematic error that you do not measure in the short time period). Also, the degrees of freedom will be wrongly estimated if the errors in succeeding days are correlated then they are more like a single observation instead of two independent observations. The effect will be that you have a larger t-value and underestimate the p-value.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree with the correlation topic and I will investigate more about that. However, as a first step I am interest in knowing if the t-test random sample assumption is being violated here. I cant establish what is my reference population.